# Can we use c++20's atomic_ref to concurrently accessing user type member function?

Tags: c++, atomic, c++20, stdatomic

Consider this problem: I have an `atomic_ref` of a user type. I want to concurrently accessing its member functions. See code below:

```
struct A{
    int counter=0;
    
    int add(){
        ++counter;
        return counter;
    };
};

int main() { 
    A a;
    std::atomic_ref<A> ra{a};
    std::vector<std::thread> v;
    for(int i=0;i<1000;++i){
        v.emplace_back([&ra]{ra.load().add();});
    };
    for(auto & t: v){t.join();};
    std::cout<<a.counter<<std::endl;
 };
```

Final output is `0` because `load()` returns a copy. Is there any other way to reach the correct result by `atomic_ref`?

And I also want to ask that, if we have an `atomic_ref<T*>`, can we use `load()` to accessing member functions, e.g. `ra.load()->add()`. Is it safe? Code will become like this:

```
struct A{
    int counter=0;
    
    int add(){
        ++counter;
        return counter;
    };
};

int main() { 
    A* a=new A;
    std::atomic_ref<A*> ra{a};
    std::vector<std::thread> v;
    for(int i=0;i<1000;++i){
        v.emplace_back([&ra]{ra.load()->add();}); //Accessing member functions.
    };
    for(auto & t: v){t.join();};
    std::cout<<a->counter<<std::endl;
 };
```

In my test, it's indeed `1000` which is correct.

Comment: In your second test, instead of 1000 threads calling `add()` once each, which have a very low chance of actually conflicting, try 2 threads calling it 1000000 times in a loop.  If you have at least 2 cores, that should quickly show you that this is no good.  I got 1815812.

Comment: @NateEldredge Yes, you are right. Each time I get totally different results. Then it's must be not safe. I think after `load()`, what we have done to the pointer is independent of the `atomic_ref`, then it won't help on synchronization.

Comment: That's right. The pointer itself, when accessed through `ra`, is atomic, just as if you had declared `std::atomic<A *> a` in the first place.  But accesses to the object it points to, much less to the individual member variables of that object, are not atomic in any way.

Answer (score 2):

Atomics are not *magical*. They only affect the loading and accessing of the reference itself, not of anything accessed *though* the reference.